# How to implement `BEGIN ATOMIC` in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, atomic, postgresql-11

What's the equivalent of Sybase ***`BEGIN ATOMIC`*** in PostgreSQL?

It should be something like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
RETURNS int
AS $$ 
BEGIN 
    BEGIN ATOMIC
        UPDATE stetment1;
        UPDATE stetment2;
        UPDATE stetment3;
    END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The three update statements must either succeed or fail all together as one.

Comment: Functions can not start or end a transaction in Postgres. The caller of the function needs to start and end the transaction. If you really need this you have to upgrade to Postgres 11 where procedures are introduced which can [control transactions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html)

Comment: i am working on version 11

Comment: Then use a procedure, not a function. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html) for details

Comment: Ok, Danke schön!

Answer (score 1):

> the three update statements must either succeed or fail all together as one..

The comments below the question are a misunderstanding. ***Every*** Postgres function is transactional and ***always*** *either succeeds or fails alltogether as one*. You'd only need a `PROCEDURE` for the opposite: to commit what's already done inside the body of a procedure.

The literal clause `BEGIN ATOMIC` is used for the new standard-SQL `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax, which has eventually been added with **Postgres 14**. But it's just as "atomic" as any other Postgres function.

Either way, with new syntax you could write:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func()
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  RETURNS void  -- since you are not returning anything
BEGIN ATOMIC
   update stetment1;
   update stetment2;
   update stetment3:
END;
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC ... END mean in a Postgresql SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BEGIN ATOMIC; ... END; statement](https://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/detail/393/) in PostgreSQL as shown below. *`BEGIN ATOMIC; ... END;` statement works only for `LANGUAGE SQL` according to [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69519777/create-a-function-in-postgresql/77598433#77598433) gives some examples with `BEGIN ATOMIC; ... END;` statement:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC; -- Here
SELECT 2 + 3;
END; -- Here
```

And actually, not using `BEGIN ATOMIC; ... END;` statement as shown below is same as above because in PostgreSQL, `BEGIN ATOMIC; ... END;` statement has nothing special, it is just a syntax and actually in PostgreSQL, a function is automatically run in a transaction to rollback if there is error:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(value INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
SELECT 2 + 3;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```