# Create a function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I am not sure how the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement works in PostgreSQL. I want to define a function (just for entertainment) such that given a number n, it prints asterisks starting from 1 up to n
So I wrote this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION asterisks(n int)
RETURNS CHAR AS
BEGIN
for i in range(1,n+1):
   print("*"*i + "\n")
END
LANGUAGE python
```

The result I want for `n=3`:

```
*
**
***
```

However, I am not sure if calling Python like that is possible. I've read that Postgres supports Python as a procedural language in here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xplang.html

Comment: There is PL/Python, typically used as "untrusted" version (`LANGUAGE plpythonu`). Be sure to read the current manual (or the one for your Postgres version), 9.4 is outdated. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html  But `LANGUAGE sql` and `LANGUAGE plpgsql` are much more commonly used. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771561/939860 Are you asking about PL/Python, or just the best way to implement your function?

Comment: Thank you. If you could give me the best way to implement the function i'll appreciate it.

Comment: Print? Why (and whereto) would you want to print from Postgres?! Write a function that returns text instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Postgres 14 or later

The simplest way would be with the new standard SQL syntax:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asterisks(n int)
  RETURNS SETOF text
RETURN repeat('*', generate_series (1, n));
```

Or better (and all standard SQL):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asterisks(n int)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT repeat('*', g) FROM generate_series (1, n) g;
END;
```

"Better" because it's easier to understand, sticks to standard SQL (more portable). Both debatable. And it sets `IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE` appropriately, which would otherwise default to `VOLATILE CALLED ON NULL INPUT PARALLEL UNSAFE`. Non-debatable.

Call:

```
SELECT asterisks(6);
```

Or, more explicitly and standard-conforming:

```
SELECT * FROM asterisks(6);
```

See:

- [`generate_series()` in the Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES)
- [Any downsides of using data type "text" for storing strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221)
- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC ... END mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/300507/3684)

#### Postgres 13 (or any version):

SQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asterisks(n int)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT repeat('*', generate_series (1, n));
$func$;
```

PL/pgSQL function with loops (looping is typically more expensive):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.asterisks(n int)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1..n LOOP
   RETURN NEXT repeat('*', i);
END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

See:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

---

Of course, for the simple example, I would just run the plain statement instead of creating a function:

```
SELECT repeat('*', generate_series (1, 3));
```

Comment: I would've thought the OP expects `SELECT string_agg(repeat('*', g), '\n') FROM generate_series (1, n) g`

Comment: @Bergi: Maybe. Looks like the OP just wanted syntax templates for basic functions.

Comment: Why is the second (more verbose) form better than the first one?

Comment: @AdamPiotrowski: OK, "better" is fuzzy. I added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in PL/pgSQL or SQL language.

For example, you create `test` table as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num INTEGER
);
```

Then, you insert the row whose `num` is `2` as shown below:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (2);
```

Now, you can create `my_func()` PL/pgSQL function which adds `value` to `num` and returns `value` to the caller as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(value INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$
BEGIN
  UPDATE test set num = num + value;
  SELECT num INTO value FROM test;
  RETURN value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or, you can create `my_func()` SQL function which adds `value` to `num` and returns `value` to the caller as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(value INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER
AS $$
UPDATE test SET num = num + value;
SELECT num FROM test;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then, you can call `my_func(3)` with [SELECT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html), then `5` is returned and `3` is added to `num` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT my_func(3);
 my_func
---------
       5
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT num FROM test;
 num
-----
   5
(1 row)
```