# How to overload the equality operator for primitive types (int, real...)?

Tags: sql, postgresql, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload the existing equality operator in PostgreSQL to give a new definition of equality between two values of type `int` or `real`? I think it's against the rules of overloading but I wonder if there's a way to do it anyway. I tried this:

```sql
CREATE OPERATOR = ( LEFTARG = real ,
                    RIGHTARG = real,
                    PROCEDURE = new_equality,
                    COMMUTATOR = = ,
                    NEGATOR = !=
                  );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_equality (real, real) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS 
$$
SELECT abs ($1 - $2) < 0,2 ;
$$ LANGUAGE PL/PGSQL
```

But when I use the equality operator in a query I don't get any result.
I also tried to define the `new_equality()` function parameters as the type of my attributes like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new_equality (Student.age%TYPE, Student.age%TYPE) RETURNS BOOLEAN 
AS
$$
SELECT abs ($1 - $2) < 0,2;
$$ lANGUAGE PL/PGSQL
```

But I get a notice saying that Postgres converts them to `real` and when I use the equality operator in a query I still don't get any result.

Comment: The code you show is not valid. Please show the code you actually executed. And always your version of Postgres, obviously.

Comment: Rather than overloading the built-in `=` operator I would define a new operator (e.g. `=~=`)  to avoid any conflicts in other areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laurenz pointed out the immediate problem `search_path`. There is more.

Assuming **Postgres 14**, this would work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_equality (real, real)  -- be explicit about the schema!
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE COST 10
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT abs($1 - $2) < 0.2;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_inequality (real, real)  -- be explicit about the schema!
  RETURNS bool
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE COST 10
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT abs($1 - $2) >= 0.2;
END;

CREATE OPERATOR public.= (             -- be explicit about the schema!
  LEFTARG    = real
, RIGHTARG   = real
, FUNCTION   = public.new_equality
, COMMUTATOR = OPERATOR(public.=)      -- be explicit about the schema!
, NEGATOR    = OPERATOR(public.!=)     -- must also exist
);

CREATE OPERATOR public.!= (
  LEFTARG    = real
, RIGHTARG   = real
, FUNCTION   = public.new_inequality
, COMMUTATOR = OPERATOR(public.!=)
, NEGATOR    = OPERATOR(public.=)
);
```

Use the `OPERATOR()` construct to call it:

```
SELECT id, real '0.1' OPERATOR(public.=) real '0.2';
SELECT id, real '0.1' OPERATOR(public.!=) real '0.2';
SELECT id, real '0.1' OPERATOR(public.<>) real '0.2';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4c3ac4ea1d268d1e235f8df499cc92cb)*  - with more examples

Be aware of the [**higher operator precedence**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE), possibly forcing parentheses where the plain operator wouldn't!

You must also ***define*** the `NEGATOR` you mention in the declaration. Using the built-in `!=` would be contradicting nonsense. Create a matching operator, which you must refer to with schema-qualified syntax. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createoperator.html)

> To give a schema-qualified operator name in **`com_op`** or the other optional arguments, use the `OPERATOR()` syntax [...]

Related:

- [How to use % operator from the extension pg_trgm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975599/how-to-use-operator-from-the-extension-pg-trgm/22975642#22975642)
- [GIN index on smallint[] column not used or error "operator is not unique"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798993/gin-index-on-smallint-column-not-used-or-error-operator-is-not-unique/39802812#39802812)

Note that `<>` is an automatic alias of `!=`, and `<>` is the default inequality operator in SQL.

An unqualified `=` will be the standard equality operator (`OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=)`) while you don't mess with the `search_path` to demote `pg_catalog` - which you shouldn't! Demoting `pg_catalog` opens the door to all kinds of serious problems, since system objects are now hidden behind one or more other schemas. **Don't** do that unless you know exactly what you are doing. About the `search_path`:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

This assumes at least Postgres 14. About `BEGIN ATOMIC`:

- [How to implement `BEGIN ATOMIC` in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394269/how-to-implement-begin-atomic-in-postgresql/69511734#69511734)

Using the keyword `FUNCTION` instead of the misleading `PROCEDURE`, which is still valid for backward compatibility. See:

- [Trigger uses a procedure or a function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/307500/3684)

Like [a_horse_with_no_name suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249867/how-to-overload-the-equality-operator-on-postgresql-using-parameters-with-primit/71252230?noredirect=1#comment125949160_71249867), it may be more convenient to use an operator symbol that is different from existing ones to avoid conflicts. Would still have standard (= higher) operator precedence than default comparison operators, and that cannot be changed easily.

Comment: Is it the operator () construct or the public.= declaration that is solving the problem ?this solution worked for me but i don't understand how the system knows when to use the default '=' or the new equality operator 'public.='

Comment: @majda: Visibility of database objects like tables, function, or operators is decided by the `search_path` (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860) **unless** explicitly schema-qualified. To do that for an operator (where that is less commonly used) apply the `OPERATOR()` construct. While the operator symbols `=` and `<>` exist in more than one schema (`public` and `pg_catalog`) in the example, they resolve to the first schema in the `search_path`, unless schema-qualified.

Comment: @majda: Operator resolution is more sophisticated than that, but schema strikes first. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46357543/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29245753/939860

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid (it should be `LANGUAGE sql`), but your operator won't get used, because `pg_catalog` is implicitly first on the `search_path`.

You can either change `search_path` to put `pg_catalog` elsewhere:

```
SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
```

or you can reference the operator explicitly:

```
SELECT 1::real OPERATOR(public.=) 1.1::real;
```

Comment: I would not advocate `SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;` for its many dangerous side effects.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter No, of course that is a bad idea. I just tried to answer the question.